# How the lines are derived?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, implicit-differentiation

Can anyone help me to understand how the last line is derived from the following equation? I am new to matrix calculus.

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
E(c) & = \parallel \textbf{R}_{3l}c -s \parallel^2 = (\textbf{R}_{3l}c -s)^{T}(\textbf{R}_{3l}c -s)\\
     & = c^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l}c-2c^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}s+s^{T}s
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Also, how the derivative of above equation with respect to coefficient vector c can be derived using matrix calculus as below:

\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial E}{\partial c}= (\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l})c+(\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l})^{T}c-2\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}s
\end{equation}

Then, how the least square solution for c is obtained by setting the derivative equal to zero:

\begin{equation} 
c=\textbf{R}_{3l}^{\dagger}s=(\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l})^{-1}\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}s
\end{equation}

Comment: It might help potential answerers if you stated something about this problem you _were_ confident about, so we would know how to extend that zone to cover the many things that seem to puzzle you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that $\frac{\partial c^TR^TRc}{\partial c} = 2R^TRc = (\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l})c+(\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}\textbf{R}_{3l})^{T}c$.

Also, $\frac{\partial c^TR^T}{\partial c} = R^T = 2\textbf{R}_{3l}^{T}s$